# I am facing an issue regarding postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

FATAL: database "collabfield_development" does not exist
Extracted source (around line #50):
48
49
50
51
52
53

```
rescue ::PG::Error => error
  if error.message.include?(conn_params[:dbname])
    raise ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError
  else
    raise
  end
```

Comment: Can you connect using `psql -d postgres -U <some_user>`? If so what does `\l` show for database name? My suspicion is that that the name got created quoted with mixed case and you will need to quote it  in your connection.

Comment: If it doesn't exist then try creating it `bundle exec rails db:create`

Comment: $ psql -U postgres
postgres=# ALTER USER username CREATEDB;

Comment: I ran these commands and  gave rights to the user to create a database as my user didn't had the rights to create a DB before.

Comment: Cool @HamzaAmin, that's enough to answer your own question.